# Doubt regarding vectors in a physics question.

Tags: geometry, vector-spaces, physics

[image]

I thought to post this doubt in mathematics section as I thought It was more of a vector question. I haven't studied vectors but there is some use in physics. Is there any theorem from which I can get the value of the above mentioned equation in the image. I was willing to find multiple equillibrium positions rather than finding only centroid of the polygon as an equllibrium position.
I am sorry if I had done something wrong in anyway , I am too naive in this.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by the square of a vector, but whatever it means I would expect it to be positive, so for your product to be zero, the thing you multiply it by ($KQq$?) has to be zero.

Comment: @GerryMyerson He is missing his unit vector directions on each term. He means that a certain vector sum is zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my comment, you don't need for the sum of inverse squared magnitudes to be zero as it will never be zero (as Gerry Myerson pointed out). What you need is for the vector sum to be zero so

$$ \sum_\ell \frac{\hat{\mathbf{r}}_\ell}{\| \mathbf{r}_\ell \|^2} = \vec{0} $$

where $\hat{\mathbf{r}}_\ell$ are the unit vectors pointing from your "test point" to particle $\ell$ in your charge distribution (or vice versa).

We can try to think of it geometrically but a closed form solution will be hard to come by on pure geometrical intuition. "Intuition" can also be misleading. I can think of at least $N+1$ points where I would imagine that the forces might sum to zero but I cannot guarantee this on intuition alone. As it turns out, analysis shows that only one of these points comes to equilibrium.

How do we know if there is only one or if there are more? We either have to have strokes of geometric genius or we can convert the problem into an algebraic one.

Consider a distribution with $N$ same-magnitude charges on the corners of a regular n-polygon. We can draw a circle such that it includes all the charges and they will be separated by equal arcs. We call this the circumscribed circle. We will develop a system that solves for the points where the electric field is equal to zero.

Since each charge in the distribution is located on a circle, we can say that charge $\ell$ is at

$$ \theta_\ell = \frac{2\pi(\ell - 1)}{N} \: \text{ where } \: k=1,2,\dots,N \text{ .}$$

Now we can say that the cartesian coordinate of charge $\ell$ is $(x,y) = (R\cos\theta_\ell,R\sin\theta_\ell)$ where $R$ is the radius of the circumscribing circle (see appendicized argument if you don't know what this is). We will now adjust our expression for the electric field as

$$ \vec{\mathbf{E}}(x,y) = kQ\sum_\ell \frac{\hat{\mathbf{r}}_\ell}{\| \mathbf{r}_\ell \|^2} = kQ\sum_\ell \frac{\vec{\mathbf{r}}_\ell}{\| \mathbf{r}_\ell \|^3} $$

$$\text{where} $$

$$ \vec{\mathbf{r}}_\ell = \begin{bmatrix}  R\cos\theta_\ell - x\\ R\sin\theta_\ell - y \end{bmatrix}$$

$$\text{and}$$

$$\| \mathbf{r}_\ell \|^2 = (x - R\cos\theta_\ell)^2 + (y - R\sin\theta_\ell)^2 \text{ .}$$

We then have the following non-linear system of equations for the equilibria

$$ \vec{\mathbf{E}}(x,y) = kQ\sum_\ell \bigg( (x - R\cos\theta_\ell)^2 + (y - R\sin\theta_\ell)^2 \bigg)^{-3/2} \begin{bmatrix} R\cos\theta_\ell - x\\ R\sin\theta_\ell - y \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0\\0 \end{bmatrix} \text{ .}$$

A solution to the above equations would yield all equilibria. I personally think it is best left to a computational solver.

Let me know if you have any questions or comments or if I've made any glaring errors.

Comment: No, there is only one; the ones on the circumcircle do not sum to zeroes, because the rest of the charges (except for the two closest ones) are all on one side of the particle.  For example, consider particle at $(1, 0)$ with four charges at $(\pm 1, \pm 1)$.  The vector sum of distance vectors, weighted by inverse Euclidean distance squared between particle and charge, is $(4/5, 0)$.  Such four charges only have an equilibrium point at origin.

Comment: @Glärbo, you misunderstand where I say the equilibrium point would be. I say that it would be somewhere along the line segment, not at the midpoint of two charges. That being said, I did the analysis along the line and it seems like my intuition on this was in fact wrong! Another reason why we should trust more in the algebra than one's geometric intuition. I'll make the appropriate edit when I have the time tonight.

Comment: Ah, sorry for the misunderstanding.  In the charges at $(\pm 1, \pm 1)$ case, on the $x$ axis ($(0,0) - (1,0)$ corresponding to one line segment you described), the weighted vector sum is$$\begin{cases} x = \frac{4 x^3}{x^4 + 4} \\ y = 0 \end{cases}$$ which obviously only has a zero at origin.  For a particle at point $(x, y)$, the vector sum is zero only when $x y^6 + 3 x^3 y^4 + 3 x^5 y^2 - 12 x y^2 + x^7 + 4 x^3 = x^6 y + 3 x^4 y^3 + 3 x^2 y^5 - 12 x^2 y + y^4 + 4 y^3 = 0$. Ignoring the charge locations ($(\pm 1, \pm 1)$), the only real solution to this is $(0, 0)$, according to Maxima...

Comment: ... which means that the only weighted vector sum for the four charges at $(\pm 1, \pm 1)$ case is at the origin, $(0, 0)$.  (We can ignore the charge locations because there the weight is $\frac{1}{0}$, which makes no sense.)

Comment: @Glärbo yes, this is similar to the analysis I whipped up this morning that told me I was definitely wrong. **Thank you for calling me out on this** (I cannot stress this enough). This reminds me of a comment I read recently describing the difference between a physicist and a mathematician. They said something to the effect of "a mathematician doesn't trust his intuition". I got a chuckle out of it but I think it also speaks volumes of wisdom.

Comment: No, thank you for considering it.  I myself make similar errors, and being notified of them is absolutely critical for me!  Not only I can then correct the errors, but I **learn**; knowing where the "blind spots" in my understanding lets me know where to concentrate next.  As to myself, I'm actually a computational materials physics toolmaker, and making more than my share of mistakes has taught me to quickly whip up test cases to verify my intuition... Because of my additional, ah, social issues, I only participate here with unregistered accounts nowadays. :-)

Comment: Can you please tell how do you know that there are N+1 points?

Comment: xy6+3x3y4+3x5y2−12xy2+x7+4x3=x6y+3x4y3+3x2y5−12x2y+y4+4y3=0 can anyone please tell something more about this

Comment: @DASH_quanta sorry for the confusion but I believe that there is only one equilibrium for any $N>1$. You may want to reread the second paragraph of my response. I was saying that there are $N$ other potential candidates based on my intuition but it turns out that those $N$ situations are not equilibria. As for Glarbo's comment, he took the special case of $N=4$ and $R=\sqrt{2}$ (but rotated 45 degrees from my solution). His formulation should indeed match the one I provided in the second half of my answer (up to a coordinate rotation of course).

Comment: I got what you are saying , thanks